# Are Advanced Snow Simulations Now Possible In Blender 4.0?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I am creating a little Eevee animation of a baby duckling popping out of snow and going for a stroll. I know dynamic paint can make footprints, but when the duckling pops out of the snow, I want a little clump of snow on his head to remain for a second and then crumble off of him. I found people asking for this in previous versions and there didn't seem to be much possible without buying add-ons. Now that we have simulation nodes, is this actually possible?

Here is a sample of what Disney did for Frozen that I am going for, particularly the bottom right:

[image]

Comment: Looks like molecular addon has been used, you can get it here https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases. But it is look a bit outdated

Comment: @Crantisz Yeah, I spotted that, but I can't find solid examples of it working. There's a couple videos that are 10 years old that are very voxellized and then one that is more recent but it is not a good example. If there are no other options, I'll give it a try.

Comment: For footprints in snow, I recommend the following video tutorial: https://youtu.be/HMpKmzTGwiE?si=9grCbxvRQf68YVlX I wouldn't say that snow simulation with nodes is impossible, but I have to be honest it's not user friendly in its current form. Not something I'd recommend to take on as a project unless you're advanced at using simulation nodes. If I was to tackle your particular shot (snow falling off the head of a small duckling) I'd say that simulation is overkill. You could easily achieve your shot with simple keyframe animation - fracture your object into clumps (studying your reference fo

Comment: I found this video that with some modifying makes a dissolving clump of snow that turns into particles that is controlled by an empty. I think it's the best current solution in Blender for the effect I was going for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD5_d0r4yv4&list=PLrlvL_yQcl5cPYysRArmQkDGR2DzO6dCR&index=59